# Is this Usecase diagram correct for My Project Plan

Tags: ruby-on-rails, uml, use-case

I'm working on an usecase diagram before build an application (using ruby on rails).

Association Model (plan) :

- student has_one user
- teacher has_one user
- user belongs_to student
- user belongs_to teacher
- user has_many topic
- user has_many comment
- topic belongs_to user
- comment belongs_to user

Attribute Per Model (plan) :

I'm using two devise (i'm not using cancan) : one devise for student authentication and other devise for teacher authentication.

- student : id, username, password, name, nis
- teacher : id, email, password, name, nip
- user : id, student_id, teacher_id (for logic : if student has_one user, teacher_id is empty and if teacher has_one user, student_id is empty)

Here's scenario for usecase :

- A student as a `user` make `a topic` and `a comment` required `login student`
- A teacher as a `user` make `a topic` and `a comment` to topic required `login teacher`

I've made ​​a usecase, but I'm not sure this is true.

[image]

**Question** : Should I make include `post topic` and `leave comment` to `login student` and `login teacher`? If that's wrong, how can i do that?

Comment: Teacher and student are both users. All users can create a topic and add comments. Why do you make the distinction between teacher and student where they both are users?

Comment: Maybe I should use one user (type: teacher and student) and can be made easily usecase, i can not give the reason but, can i make usecase with above case?

Comment: You can make a case based on the information you have provided. Your translation into the use case is imho incorrect.

Comment: Where I get a reference to my case? I tried looking via google did not find a similar case. To be honest I do not understand in the making usecase. I was just thinking about this all night

Comment: It is also not easy to grasp. There are similar cases though. But you have to be able to recognize them. For that you need time to develop the knowledge what an use case is. Basically is it a list of steps describing the interaction between an actor and the system. Your use case has an user logging in, registered users creating a topic and registered users commenting on topics. Try to describe that in steps, maybe start first using words to describe what has to be done. An use case is a visual presentation of those steps.

Comment: You may able to develop this better than this. slightly good. Try to point out the exact user scenarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some of the errors in your representation, imho:

1. User, Teacher and Student are redundant in this diagram.
   Isn't there any "functionality" which only one of Teacher or Student should use? This would make any sense but you would have to draw a new diagram.
2. "Login XX" should never be represented as a Use Case. There is a whole discussion on this topic but this is a common sense in the market. Use cases must represent functionalities which are valueable to the user and login brings no value to him. There is another common sense which says that use cases should be adequate to the following scenario:

Imagine that the user's boss comes to him with a big smile in the face in the middle of the afternoon and asks him:

-"What are you doing now?"
The answer the boss is expecting to hear is not "I'm logging in". It should be: "I'm calculating the order volume for today" (A) or "I'm generating the monthly report" (B).

Hence there would be 2 use cases here:

A = Calculate Order Volume
B = Generate Monthly Report

something like this...